# trouble to link authStateChange stream to my Bloc and add events (authenticated and unauthenticated)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, bloc

So i know i can just make a streambuilder and put FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChange() in the stream property and it works fine. But i want to use bloc since it is cleaner and the most popular way of doing things in flutter. Just for reference i am still a newbie so i am having trouble to create a stream that feeds of AuthStateChange() stream provided by firebase to inject events (authenticated and unauthenticated) in my bloc... i was trying to do the code below but i am stuck, i cant think of any possible solution. can someone help me?

```
enum UserState { authenticated, unauthenticated }

class User {
  UserState _state = UserState.unauthenticated;

  final StreamController<UserState> _controller =
      StreamController<UserState>.broadcast();

  Stream<UserState> get stream => _controller.stream;

  Stream authStateChanges() async* {
    // when FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(); changes then call the function changeState
    // to add authenticated and unauthenticated to the stream _controller and then i will link it with my bloc
    // and make my enum UserState like 2 possible events
  }

  void changeState(UserState state) {
    if (_state != state) {
      _state = state;
      _controller.add(state);
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

trying to learn more about flutter firebaseauth and understand how stream and bloc works together